# I want to delete an image stored in different domain from my website. i use unlink($location_of_file) but it does not work

Tags: php

Image is stored in domain : www.example.com/image/image1.jpeg.
and I want to delete that image from my site : www.deleteimage.com/delete.php
I use the unlink function :unlink(www.example.com/image/image1.jpeg) but it doesnot work .

Comment: you have to pass physical (realpath) path in unlink function.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: check you have proper permission. and put your code in try catch block you will get exact error.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't delete image stored on another server. If that is allowed, you can delete images from any of the site that you wish to ;-) 
What you should do is, create an secured script for deleting image on another site where the image is being stored. And make a call to that script from your server.

Comment: I use curl function here :      $ch=curl_init();         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://$ftpName:$ftpPass@$ftpHost") or die("error on creating ftp+uname+upass()");;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_QUOTE, array($delfile)) or die("error on creating curlopt_quote()");;
  curl_exec($ch) or die("error on execting()");   here I got error from curl_exec($ch) function..Do you have any Idea why this error came.

Answer (score 1):

If you have both websites on the same hosting it is possible, just supply physical path, let's say the folder structure on your hosting looks like this

```
/yourhome
|- /yourhome/example.com
| |- /yourhome/example.com/web/
| \- /yourhome/example.com/logs/
|
\- /yourhome/deleteimage.com/
  |- /yourhome/deleteimage.com/web/
  \- /yourhome/deleteimage.com/logs/
```

You could then supply unlink path that would look like this:

```
../../example.com/web/image/image1.jpeg
```

If those domains are not same hosting you could create script on example.com to delete demanded image, from deleteimage.com you would just call [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and specify image in GET args. This is however discouraged approach because it would create security hole in example.com and most probably anyone could delete any of your files from example.com once they find out about the script.